# Python + Selenium) How can I get this thing clicked?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, automated-tests

**Question.**
I'm really new to Python and can't find a way to click this link.
My aim was to click the links one by one, and I got stuck from clicking the first link.
I searched several times and tried even more, but I can't even find what is the problem!
The links lead to a new window(Survey), and the following is the html structure.

```html
<div id="bb_deployment6" class="stream_item active_stream_item" role="listitem" x-aria-selected="true" tabindex="0" style="padding-left: 20px;"><span class="stream_datestamp">1 hour</span><div class="stream_context">Survey <a href="#" onclick="popup.launch('https://websitename', 'instrumentResponseWindow')">[Today] Survey A</a>: Click to submit survey </div><div class="stream_details"></div><div class="stream_context_bottom"></div></div>

<div id="bb_deployment5" class="stream_item" role="listitem" x-aria-selected="false" tabindex="-1" style="padding-left: 20px;"><span class="stream_datestamp">2 hour</span><div class="stream_context">Survey <a href="#" onclick="popup.launch('https://Websitename2', 'instrumentResponseWindow')">[Today] Survey B</a>: Click to submit survey </div><div class="stream_details"></div><div class="stream_context_bottom"></div></div>
```

Here's what I've tried

1. First Shot

```css
from selenium import webdriver
browser =webdriver.Chrome("C:\Pii\selenium\chromedriver.exe")

#Open the Site
browser.get("https://that site")

#Find & Click!!
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Survey").click()
```

The first error code was

: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"partial link text","selector":"Survey"}

2. Second Shot: OK Maybe the loading time was too short?

```css
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser =webdriver.Chrome("C:\Pii\selenium\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://that site")

#Wait & Click
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Survey")))
browser.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Survey").click()
```

and now it said

: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

3. Third Shot: Maybe the click part was the problem because of onclick?

```css
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Pii\selenium\chromedriver.exe")

browser.get("https://that site")


wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Survey")))


sample = browser.find_element_by_link_text("Survey")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",sample)
```

and it said

: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

The same message as above

4. Fourth Shot: Maybe I should use XPATH instead of text?

```css
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:\Pii\selenium\chromedriver.exe")


browser.get("https://that site")

wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="bb_deployment5"]/div[1]/a')))
sample = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bb_deployment5"]/div[1]/a')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",sample)
```

and the result was the same

I think I got something totally wrong, but I can't get what that is.
Any answer would be a great help. Thanks

Comment: Hi Lali, welcome to stack overflow. Is your element located in an iframe? Or, does it need to be scrolled into view to get it to appear in the DOM? - both require a little bit of extra handling

Comment: Have you tried find_elements_by_partial_link_text instead? It returns a list, and then you can loop through them. find_element_by_partial_link_text only returns one element

Comment: @RichEdwards The element is located in an iframe. The biggest frame goes like: <div class="iframe-wrap" id="iframe_wrap">  </div> Can this be the reason why I can't get this through?

Comment: @Lali is the element located within an ```iframe```? You should have told it earlier...What is the class/id of the ```iframe```?

Comment: @izzulmakin Yep I did try elements_by_partial_link_test and made a loop but it still couldn't locate anything. What IS wrong with this line..

Comment: @Sushil The iframe class is "cloud-iframe" and the id is "mybbCanvas"!! I didn't know iframe was so important.. Long way to go

Comment: Lol...Okay that's not an issue. I have updated my solution. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the element is located in a different `iframe`, you should switch focus to that `iframe` and then search for the element. This is how you do it:

```
iframe = browser.find_element_by_class_name('cloud-iframe')
browser.switch_to.frame(iframe)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="bb_deployment5"]/div[1]/a')))
element.click()
```

This should work, but I am not 100% sure as I haven't yet seen the website myself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but "Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[contains(text(), 'Survey ')]"}" this comes out again. There really is 'Survey', but can't the program locate this?

Comment: You should have informed us earlier that the element is present within an ```iframe```. Anyways, I have updated my solution. Check it out and let me know whether it works for u.

Comment: It didn't work with the partial link test(don;t know why), so I tried with the XPATH and this thing works! The problem was that iframe.. Thanks for answering such a newbie. Saved my day

Comment: And which xpath worked for u? Was it this: ```sample = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bb_deployment5"]/div[1]/a')```?

Comment: @Lali Okay...I have updated my solution so that it contains this xpath ```sample = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="bb_deployment5"]/div[1]/a')``` Glad to have helped you!